# How to find a postion of the lowest value in the file?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

How to output position of a line with the lowest value inside?

I have a file with data like below:

```
2233|charles harris  |g.m.     |sales     |12/12/52| 90000
9876|bill johnson    |director |production|03/12/50|130000
5678|robert dylan    |d.g.m.   |marketing |04/19/43| 85000
2365|john woodcock   |director |personnel |05/11/47|120000
5423|barry wood      |chairman |admin     |08/30/56|160000
1006|gordon lightfoot|director |sales     |09/03/38|140000
```

I need to find a lowest value from the last column and return its position

Comment: This should be a simple `awk` exercise. Keep two variables, the lowest value seen so far, and the line number where it was found. Whenever you get a value that's lower than the first variable, update the two variables from the current row. At the end, print the two variables.

Comment: Or use `cat -n` piped to a sort, piped to `head -1`, piped to `awk`. Example if the file is foo.txt: `cat -n foo.txt | sort -t\| -n -k 6,6 | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`. Remove the awk to print the complete line prepended by what its original line number was, or adjust awk to just print the line without the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command in order to get only the line number where the value is shown(if the value appears more than one time then it will give several line numbers):

```
var=$(cut -d "|" -f 6 filename|sort -nr|tail -n1|grep -w -n -f /dev/stdin filename|awk -F ":" '{print $1}');cut -d "|" -f 6 filename |grep -w -n $var filename|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
```

in order to see the line with the lowest value and it's line number use this command:

```
var=$(cut -d "|" -f 6 filename|sort -nr|tail -n1|grep -w -n -f /dev/stdin filename|awk -F ":" '{print $1}');cut -d "|" -f 6 filename |grep -w -n $var filename
```